# Interrogation about the RxJS 5 filter() operator

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, ngrx

I have an angular 2 router guard whose `canActivate` method is defined as follows:

```
canActivate() {
    return this.sessionSigninService.isAuthenticated()
      .filter(isAuthenticated => isAuthenticated !== null)
      .map(isAuthenticated => {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
          return true;
        }
        this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
        return false;
      });
  }
```

from `sessionSigninService`:

```
  isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.select(fromRoot.getAuthenticated);
  }
```

FYI, `fromRoot.getAuthenticated` is initialized with a value of `null`

When the `canActivate` method is called and a `null` value for `isAuthenticated` enters into the `filter()` operator, it seems the `filter()` blocks until the value of `isAuthenticated` changes to `false` or `true`.

Note that this is the desired behavior but I don't understand it...

Can someone please explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Like Array.prototype.filter(), it only emits a value from the source if it passes a criterion function.

[`filter`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-filter) will only propagate data when the returned value of the filter-method is `true` - when you have `isAuthenticated: null` and evaluate `null !== null` -> it will return `false`, that's why no data is propagated and the `map` will not be called.

As soon as you have `isAuthenticated: true|false`, the filter will evaluate to `true`, because both `true` and `false` are `!== null`, and propagate data.

Comment: Thanks olsn. What is the correct RxJS terminology in order to describe this behavior? Is it correct to say that the `filter` operator **blocks** so long as the predicate does not evalutate to true?

Comment: I'd go with the name of the operator and say "__filters out__" - the word "__blocks__" to me would sound like the data could be _unblocked_ at a later point in time, which is not the case, the data is simply _"gone"_